# pass a variable to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

this title seems pretty common, but i can't find a correct answer for my problem from them.

I have a bootstrap template, and what i want to do is to pass some variable to a modal.

I'm using codeigniter and also smarty..

this is the code from my template:

```
<td><a class="btn mini red-stripe" href="#myModal3" data-id="{$frontuser->id}" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Eliminar</a></td> 

<!-- modal -->
    <div id="myModal3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-     labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">  </button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Eliminar Usuario Front</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Desea eliminar el usuario "{$frontuser->username}"?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn blue">Confirmar</button>

    </div>
    </div>
<!-- end modal -->
```

i tried to find a JS file in order to analize it and see if i have to make some moedifications in there, but i didn't find a js that controls this. So, is this meaning that my modal is entirely managed by html?

if that's so..where do i put the variable in order to make the modal show this info?

thx

Comment: can you please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this so we can properly see the issue. thanks

Comment: You'll have to add it through javascript, add a listener & change the text accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like PHP variables which you have to wrap in `<?php [...] ?>`.

---

Try this version

```
<td>
    <a class="btn mini red-stripe" href="#myModal3" data-id=<?php echo $frontuser->id; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Eliminar</a></td> 

<!-- modal -->
    <div id="myModal3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-     labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">  </button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Eliminar Usuario Front</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Desea eliminar el usuario <?php echo $frontuser->username; ?>?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn blue">Confirmar</button>

    </div>
    </div>
<!-- end modal -->
```

If you are using a specific template and wish to stick to the templates syntax, you may do so accordingly. The above snippet should work regardless.

Cheers

Comment: I did that before but didn't work. is a js necessary?

Comment: does the modal work all by itself without the variables? just pure HTML

Comment: yes, it's not even calling js functions...so, i still can't make it to pass data to the modal :(